# Stuck on Exercise 28 of Learn Ruby Hard Way - different returns in irb

Tags: ruby

Currently doing exercise 28 link here: http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex28.html

Under 'Common Student Questions', there's the following:

**Question**

Why does "test" && "test" return "test" or 1 && 1 return 1 instead of true?

**Answer**

Ruby and many languages like to return one of the operands to their boolean expressions rather than just true or false. This means that if you did false && 1 you get the first operand (false) but if you do true && 1 your get the second (1). Play with this a bit.

---

However, even after reading the answer above, I'm still having trouble understanding why

*false && 1* returns 'false'

while

*true && 1* returns '1'

in irb.

Answer (score 2):

Foreword: in Ruby just `false` itself and `nil` are `false`. Everything else is evaluated to `true`.

`false && 1`

`e1` and `e2` have both to be `true` to make the entire expression evaluate to `true`. `e1` is `false` so there is no need to evaluate e2. `e1` (`false`) is returned.

`true && 1`

`e1` is `true` so we need to evaluate even `e2` and `e2` is `1`. `1` is returned.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. If 'false' is part of the equation, then just returns false regardless. If 'true' is part of it, and instead of returning true, it'll return the '1' instead.

Comment: Yes but that is just true for &&. If we had `false || 1` it would evaluate e2 too because just one true is enough to make the entire expression to be true.

Comment: _Sidenote_: in Ruby world there is a custom to call `nil` and `false` being **`falsey`**, and others being **`truthy`**. Otherwise you got the mess that you have within your [perfectly correct] answer. Compare: “`e1` and `e2` have both to be **`truthy`**”.

Comment: It’s definitely waaaay better than my Italian :) The main reason in using `falsey` instead of `false` is that `nil == false` evaluates to `false`, making `nil` being [OMG, that’s hard to spell!] _not `false`, but still `falsey`_. Anyway, I hope you get the point.